# How does casting between pointer-interconvertible objects work in cases of ambiguity?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, language-lawyer, c++20

The standard ([[expr.static.cast#13]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13)) says that:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”. [...]
> If the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with a, the result is a pointer to b.
> Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

To me, this sounds a bit like there should always be at most one such object `b` that is pointer-interconvertible with `a`. But consider the following example:

```
struct X { };
struct Y { X xx; };
union Z { X x; Y y; };
```

All of the above types are standard layout classes ([[class.prop#3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#3)). In the following code:

```
Z z = {};
```

the object `z` is pointer-interconvertible ([[basic.compound#4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4)) with `z.x`, but also with `z.y.xx` (because `z` is pointer-interconvertible with `z.y`, and `z.y` is pointer-interconvertible with `z.y.xx`).
Therefore, my question is: **which of the objects will the following pointer refer to?** (I'm using `reinterpret_cast` because it's equivalent to `static_cast`ing to `void*` and then to `X*`)

```
X* ptr = reinterpret_cast<X*>(&z);
```

I am aware that in my example, `z.y` is not within its lifetime, but I assume that isn't a problem, because [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) has a similar example where one of the objects is not within its lifetime:

```
[...]
union U { int a; double b; } u = {0};
[...]
int* p3 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&u);  // value of p3 is "pointer to u.a": u.a and u are
                                       // pointer-interconvertible
 
double* p4 = reinterpret_cast<double*>(p3); // value of p4 is "pointer to u.b": u.a and
                                            // u.b are pointer-interconvertible because
                                            // both are pointer-interconvertible with u
```

Comment: _How does casting between pointer-interconvertible objects work in cases of ambiguity?_ It is unknown. http://wg21.link/p1839r4#16 has possible (incomplete) wording fix (but there are ppl unhappy about its outcomes)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the answer to my question.

Comment: FYI, unions also have issues with subobject replacement (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2.sentence-4), see https://lists.isocpp.org/sg12/2021/10/0984.php, except that there is no ambiguity but a non-tree shaped subobject relation graph.